# Bash: reading a short text file to a variable loses last empty line

Tags: bash

I have a script that processes a number of small files from a slow mass memory.

For performance reasons I read the file to a variable, and all processing then happens using this variable. This allows me to read each file only once.

This works well, except when the last line is empty, then the variable will be one line shorter than the file, see simplified example below.

Is there a way to read empty lines in the end of the file to a variable?

```
$ rm -f /tmp/a ; for i in $(seq 3) ; do echo $i >> /tmp/a ; done
$ cat /tmp/a
1
2
3
$ wc -l /tmp/a
3 /tmp/a
$ a="$(cat /tmp/a)"
$ echo "$a"
1
2
3
$ echo "$a" | wc -l
3

$ rm -f /tmp/b ; for i in $(seq 3) ; do echo $i >> /tmp/b ; done
$ echo >> /tmp/b # ADD EXTRA EMPTY LINE TO THE END
$ cat /tmp/b
1
2
3

$ wc -l /tmp/b
4 /tmp/b
$ b="$(cat /tmp/b)"
$ echo "$b"
1
2
3
$ echo "$b" | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 7):

`$(...)` strips all trailing newlines. From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may  be  removed during word splitting.  The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

Use `mapfile` to read the entire file in while preserving newlines. It reads each line into an array.

```
$ mapfile b < /tmp/b
$ printf '%s' "${b[@]}"
1
2
3

$ printf '%s' "${b[@]}" | wc -l
4
```

Avoid `echo`, which adds an extra newline. `printf '%s'` doesn't do that, so you're getting exactly what's in the array.

If don't want an array you can use `printf -v` to flatten it into a single string while preserving newlines.

```
$ mapfile b < /tmp/b
$ printf -v b '%s' "${b[@]}"
$ printf '%s' "$b"
1
2
3

$ printf '%s' "$b" | wc -l
4
```

---

> For performance reasons I read the file to a variable, and all processing then happens using this variable. This allows me to read each file only once.

This may be premature optimization. Once a file is read from disk the OS will keep it in cache. Re-reading files that are still in cache is extremely fast.

Comment: On which version is `printf -v` available?

Comment: Bash 3.1 or later.

Comment: You might want to use the `-t` option with `mapfile`, which will strip the newline character at the end of each line, but without discarding any resulting empty lines.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks, I see that `printf -v` works even though it's not mentioned at all in the man pages.

Comment: `man printf` will show the help for `/usr/bin/printf`, which is misleading since `printf` is a shell built-in. There's a note tucked at the bottom: "NOTE: your shell may have its own version of printf, which usually supersedes the version  described  here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports." That would be `help printf`.

Comment: You can directly get the number of lines from the number of array elements `${#b[@]}`. You don't have to pipe all the content through `wc`.